# Getting the correct query for values between the range (inclusive)

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am writing an Iphone app and using sqlite as my database. I have a discount for objects if they are between a certain range (MIN and MAX), but the problem is when i do my query, the discounts seems to apply beyond that range as well. Not sure how to do it properly.

For example, I want the range between 36(MIN) to 60(MAX).

The sql statement looks like this:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM DISCOUNT WHERE PACKAGEID = '%@' AND CATEGORYID = '%@' AND '%@' >= MIN ORDER BY MAX DESC ",item.packageid,item.categoryid,item.discount];
```

This code is my senior's. Need to change it.. Need some help on it... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really have columns named MIN and MAX in your table? And are they really strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `AND '%@' <= MAX` in the query at the end after `AND '%@' >= MIN`

Your query should look like

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"
SELECT * FROM DISCOUNT WHERE PACKAGEID = '%@' AND CATEGORYID = '%@' 
AND '%@' >= MIN AND '%@' <= MAX ORDER BY MAX DESC",
item.packageid,item.categoryid,item.discount,item.discount];
```